# Application Link account creation doesn't call the response URL

Tags: sonos

[In the documentation](http://musicpartners.sonos.com/node/462), it says that the sign-in and create-account workflows should fall back to the browser workflow following the `regUrl` in `deviceLink` if you leave out the `appUrl` sub-element.

It works for the sign-in workflow but not for the create-account workflow. When I click on the **Create Account** button, it takes me to **www.sonos.com/<*ServiceName*>/subscribe** (just like the previous `getDeviceLinkCode` workflow) instead of the desired `regUrl`.

Is it a bug and it is supposed to go to my URL? Is it supposed to work and I am doing something wrong?

My Sonos System Version is 7.4 (build 37244160)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid our docs are incorrect on this. We'll get them fixed.

`deviceLink` is ignored in `createAccount`, and the signup url (serviceName/subscribe) that you noted is invoked. This url is set up as a redirect to a url you provide when we integrate your service with Sonos.